# DDclient is not able to open files owned by ddclient

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora

I am trying to setup ddclient, but there seems to be a permission problem.

```
heimchen@localhost ~> ls -l /etc/ddclient.conf
-rw-------. 1 ddclient ddclient 8110 Jan 21 23:04 /etc/ddclient.conf
heimchen@localhost ~> ddclient
WARNING:  file /etc/ddclient.conf: Cannot open file '/etc/ddclient.conf'. (Permission denied)
stat() on closed filehandle FD at /usr/sbin/ddclient line 1167.
Use of uninitialized value $mode in bitwise and (&) at /usr/sbin/ddclient line 1168.
readline() on closed filehandle FD at /usr/sbin/ddclient line 1180.
WARNING:  file /etc/ddclient.conf: Cannot open file '/etc/ddclient.conf'. (Permission denied)
stat() on closed filehandle FD at /usr/sbin/ddclient line 1167.
Use of uninitialized value $mode in bitwise and (&) at /usr/sbin/ddclient line 1168.
readline() on closed filehandle FD at /usr/sbin/ddclient line 1180.
```

Why does ddclient say it has no permissions?

The file ddclient.conf only has ~300 Lines

Replicate:

```
Fedora Server 37
sudo dnf update
sudo dnf install ddclient
ddclient
(configure /etc/ddclient.conf)
sudo systemctl enable ddclient.service
sudo systemctl start ddclient.service
```

Comment: Does it still say that if you run it _as the "ddclient" user_ and not under your own account?

Comment: How do I get into ddclient as user

Comment: Ehst does "getenforce" say? Maybe its an selinux issue?

Answer (score 0):

The file is not owned by the *program* "ddclient", it is owned by the *user account* named "ddclient".

Programs will only be allowed to read it if they're running as that user – which is not the case in your example; the ddclient program is being run under the "heimchen" account which has no permissions to access the file. This applies equally to `nano /etc/ddclient.conf` or `cat /etc/ddclient.conf`.

Starting the program as a service will automatically run it under the correct user account, as the .service configuration has `User=ddclient` specified in it; starting it directly, however, always runs it under the user account of whoever started it.

Compare with `sudo -u ddclient ddclient` or `sudo -u ddclient cat /etc/ddclient.conf`, which *do* switch to the specified user account.

---

The `.` next to basic file permissions indicates that additional restrictions (security labels) from SELinux can apply, but that's only relevant if the basic permissions allow access (as SELinux can only restrict access further, not relax the checks).